# Ubuntu Touch OS

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a **Micromax Canvas Doodle** running on Android that I don't use anymore.

> There **is No Official UBUNTU TOUCH ROM available for my phone.** Could
>   anyone provide me with the unofficial build? 
>   I just want to try UBUNTU
>   TOUCH.

P.S My **bootloader is unlocked** and I have **ROOT.**

Comment: Canonical (the Ubuntu company) have killed Ubuntu Touch project, please ask the good people at [UBports](https://ubports.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Touch is still available, you can see the list of devices [here](https://ubuntu-touch.io/devices)

Unfortunately, for now there is no unofficial version.